# GES/GOES Application ID error during background verification

Tags: indian-citizens, vfs-global, global-entry, trusted-traveler

I have applied for the US Global Entry Program through the [TTP website](https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/dashboard). I have filled out the application and paid the fee. For background verification in India, I have registered an account on the [Passportseva website](https://portal1.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/user/userLogin), but after entering all the details, it is showing that the GES/GOES Application ID or date of birth is incorrect. I have attached an image of this issue. The application ID I entered is a 9-digit number that was shown on the TTP dashboard. Could anyone help me with this issue?

> Please enter GES/GOES Application ID (without spaces). The GES Application ID has also been sent through mail by passport.admin@passportindia.gov.in on your registered email id.

[image: GES/GOES application id error]

Comment: The page says it may take upto a day for GOES application ID to be available in Indian system. Have you waited out that period of time?

Comment: YES...it's been one week

Comment: I am getting the same error. Any update after Jan 21?

Comment: Aniket Marathe till now there is no update.. i tried today as well still showing the same error

Comment: It took 10 days to get my GES ID. I hope you got yours too.